# How to hide Edit menu on certain state for every user?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I have a scheduled action that will run every now and then to process orders in a certain state, which I will call it `processing` status.

I am looking for a solution to hide Edit menu to every user when the state is `processing`. However, the scheduled action must still be able to execute CRUD to the records.

This is because I need to have the users wait for the `processing` state to be processed by the system itself without any changing of the record in between the process.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that but with a hack, so I am not sure if this would be recommended method

Make a computed field(type HTML, sanitize False,save true) in that model and also add that field in XML

```
            if rec.state in ['approved']:
                rec.computed_field_value= "<script>$('.o_form_button_edit').remove()</script>"
```

This will hide the button but now you have add it again, in else

```
         else:
              rec.computed_field_value= "<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary o_form_button_edit" accesskey="a">Edit</button>"
```

The issue with this solution:

1. Open a record in a non-processing state, click edit, and go to the next record the edit button is hidden, but you can still edit it as you are in edit mode

**How to overcome this issue**
Use constraints as well to make sure your logic cannot be challenged and the data stays sane. This can be done on the `write(self,vals)` method
the second option is to hide the save button as well.

for save `o_form_button_save`, this class will be used you can check classes from inspect element and hide and remove values accordingly